# Site issues and issues with banning users

Tags: discussion, down-votes, account-suspension

This site has many issues. Even though they have very good things for asking a good question / good answering, but here are some experts who have gained some privileges to ban any person.

This is not good. There are some people who do this very constantly, so experts, I can say, if you have knowledge, share and correct question of users. Users can ask anything, don't forget you were on same stage when you say to the user, what kind of question is this, or downvote the question or ban it.

So take it easy and let users ask the questions they need.

I have seen this, I asked one question and I was banned, same question was asked by another person and his was answered.

So help with this all, especially for ColdFusion developers.

Comment: Having high rep does not give anyone the ability to ban others, and you don't get banned for asking a single question - it takes a significant amount of bad _and non-rectified_ questions. Go **read http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans** for details.

Comment: Can you provide us with a link to both questions, so we can decide on hard data.

Comment: "i asked one question and i was banned" - That's not true. You can't be banned after a single bad question, or even two bad questions. If this is referring to that account I think it is, there were many more than one downvoted, closed, or deleted questions before the ban kicked in.

Answer (score -8):

With power comes ego, and abuse, and the situation you describe above with two similar questions being asked and one resulting in a ban and another in an answer seems unfair.

But overall the system seems to work well. The value of having an expert or skilled programmer answer a question, often within several minutes of posting it, is excellent. And it's free - how much money + time would it cost to find an answer without Stack Overflow? Especially after two hours of slamming your keyboard at your wit's end?

Being able to ban users, community self-moderation, is important to maintain the quality of answers and the health of the discussion as a whole, but certainly based on the facts given, seems to have gone awry. Everyone starts at the bottom and it's a measure of character of those at the top who remember that. But Stack is a great tool to learn + improve our code, and the risk of being banned, for me at least, is outweighed by that fact.

Comment: In response to your final sentence, there is no "risk" of being banned - as per the page I linked above it's an automated mechanism in response to _significant amounts_ of poorly asked questions _that have not subsequently been improved_. Anyone can be stressed and ask a poor question - but only if you _consistently_ ask bad questions _and ignore the advice on how to improve_ does the question ban come into effect - and even then it can be undone with positive contributions (i.e. useful answers/comments/etc)